# A set of message broadcasters and a broadcast manager

Tags: python

I'm designing an application that will broadcast messages to various heterogeneous systems. Slack, JIRA, Database to name a few. Users can pass their various configurations using a yaml file.

While this works fine, it seems verbose and somewhat excessive. Each run only ever needs a single instance of each, so having a manager and all these classes feels like a lot.

**Is there a better or more refined way to do this?**

I've set it up like so:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Broadcaster(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def broadcast(self, message, **kwargs):
        pass

class SlackBroadcaster(Broadcaster):
    def __init__(self, channel: str):
        self.channel = channel
    
    def broadcast(self, message):
        print(f"This is a slack message: {message}")

class DatabaseBroadcaster(Broadcaster):
    def __init__(self, connection: str):
        self.connection = connection
  
    def broadcast(self, message):
        print(f"This is a database message: {message}")
```

Since users can have multiple broadcasters, I've added a manager class to handle that:

```
import enum
import typing as ta

class MessageType(enum.Enum):
    """ Possible broadcasters"""

    SLACK = "slack"
    DATABASE = "database"

class BroadcasterManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.broadcaster_types = {
            MessageType.DATABASE: DatabaseBroadcaster,
            MessageType.SLACK: SlackBroadcaster,
        }
        self.broadcasters = set()

    def create_broadcaster(self, broadcaster_type: MessageType, **kwargs):
        assert broadcaster_type in self.broadcaster_types, 'Illegal broadcaster type'
        return self.broadcaster_types[broadcaster_type](**kwargs)

    def add_broadcaster(self, broadcaster_type, **kwargs):
        self.broadcasters.add(
            self.create_broadcaster(broadcaster_type, **kwargs))

    def broadcast(self, messages: ta.List[str]):
        for broadcaster in self.broadcasters:
            for message in messages:
                broadcaster.broadcast(message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some review context missing.
I didn't see any callers, didn't see any unit tests.

What you presented seems nice enough.

> seems verbose and somewhat excessive.

Yeah, it feels a bit java-esque.

> Each run only ever needs a single instance of each, so having a manager and all these classes feels like a lot.

Oohhhh, well *there's* an interesting detail.

I am taking a "run" to be "bash forked a python interpreter,
which briefly ran the script and soon exited".
Python script startup / imports can be expensive, can cost more than 1 second.
Be sure to avoid `import`ing a Slack module that's never used
by a database broadcast, immediately followed by the child process exiting.

> Is there a better or more refined way to do this?

Here's two alternatives that relate to long-lived processes.

1. You might leave this script running for hours on end, listening for requests, and thereby amortize the one-time startup cost of several imports.
2. You might make this script *only* know how to submit broadcast requests to [kafka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Kafka)
   or similar pub/sub channels,
   which slack and database daemons are listening on.

---

Honestly, I don't see that `add_broadcaster()`
is bringing a whole lot of value-add to the table.
Consider removing it from the Public API.

```
class SlackBroadcaster(Broadcaster):
    def __init__(self, channel: str):
    ...
class DatabaseBroadcaster(Broadcaster):
    def __init__(self, connection: str):
```

Let's focus on the `channel` and `connection` parameters.
Consider putting a `*,` bare star before them.
It appears to me that Author's Intent is caller
should specify those parameters with explicit keywords.
Adding a star would clarify that for the caller,
forcing them to use that calling convention.
That way they arrive via `**kwargs`.

---

```
    assert broadcaster_type in self.broadcaster_types, 'Illegal broadcaster type'
```

Good, this is helpful.

Suppose the assert triggers.
What's the next thing a maintenance engineer is going to want to know?

Recommend you use this for the 2nd argument:

`f'Illegal broadcaster type: {broadcaster_type}'`